# How to unbox a C# object to dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting, dynamictype

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
void someMethod(TypeA object) { ... }

void someMethod(TypeB object) { ... }

object getObject()
{
    if (...) return new TypeA();
    else return new TypeB();
}

object obj = getObject();
(obj.GetType()) obj;  // won't compile
someMethod(obj);
```

Obviously I'm confused here.  I know I could make this work by just writing out a conditional statement --

```
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(TypeA)) obj = (TypeA)obj;
else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(TypeB)) obj = (TypeB)obj;
```

-- but isn't there some way to do this at runtime?

**EDIT**
I agree it seems like perhaps not the best design choice, so here's the context.  The point of the above code is Repository base class for Mongo DB.  I want it to be able to handle different kinds of tables.  So, someMethod() is actually *remove*; and TypeA and TypeB are *ObjectID* and *Guid*; the code at the bottom is part of a type-agnostic *remove* method that accepts the ID as a string; and getObject() is a method to parse the ID parameter.

Comment: You are conflating a type `T` with the runtime type information associated with it: `typeof(T)`.  They are not the same thing and cannot be substituted for each other.

Comment: There are likely to be better design choices, but you left the actual goal of the code out of your post.  Maybe we could provide you with a better and totally different way of writing the solution to your problem if you let us know what you were trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: @Kirk Woll, I know the difference, I just wanted to illustrate what I was trying to do.

Comment: @John Fisher, added the context.  I gather that would be maybe a question for "Code Review" exchange, but if you have ideas, I'd be happy to open it as a separate question.

Comment: Have a look at [Massive](http://wekeroad.com/2011/02/16/and-i-shall-call-it-massive/).  You'll find a lot of good ideas there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4 and C# 4, you can use `dynamic` for this:

```
dynamic obj = GetObject();
SomeMethod(obj);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use reflection to find and invoke the right method. Overload resolution (for non-`dynamic` types) is performed at *compile*-time.

(Note that unless `TypeA` and `TypeB` are structs, you wouldn't be *unboxing* anyway...)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not given the way the question's written, where it's picking overloads within the same type.

Comment: I wasn't aware that overload resolution extended to the runtime type of the `dynamic` object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's the whole point of `dynamic` - that effectively pretty much *everything* is deferred to execution time, using the actual type of the object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: About the only thing that doesn't extend to `dynamic` is extension methods; those are only available at compile time.